# Using jsoup for validation

Tags: jsoup

Is it possible to use jsoup to validate an HTML fragment? I want to know if the markup is malformed, and instead of having jsoup fix it automatically, I want to be able to inform the user to fix the source markup itself.

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup is not the right parser for checking validity of xml or html, you can use JDom instead. Below is a sample code to check for welformedness of xml.

```
      SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
      File xmlFile = new File("sample.xml");

        try {
            Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch(JDOMException e){
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

You can download JDom2 [here](http://www.jdom.org/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess Jsoup is not the proper library for this; its used for parsing / cleaning / working on html.